# MongoDB projection toListAsync() method not supported

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use projection in my query and get the following error:
 "The result operation MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Expressions.ResultOperators.ListResultOperator is not supported." 
Here is the code:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Listing>> LoadAllUserListings(string userId)
        {
            var result = _context.Listing.Aggregate().Match(l => l.OwnerId == userId || l.Sales.Any(a => a.Owner.Id == userId)).
                 Project(l => new Listing
                 {
                     Id = l.Id,
                     Reference = l.Reference,
                     OwnerId = l.OwnerId,
                     Sales = l.Sales.Where(a => a.Owner.Id == userId || a.Manager.Id == userId).ToList(),
                     Products = l.Products,
                     Status = l.Status,
                     DueDate = l.DueDate
                 }).ToListAsync();

            return await result;
        }
```

It does not appear to like the ToListAsync call. I got this code snippet from the following answer:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904811/mongodb-c-sharp-filter-and-get-all-subdocuments](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904811/mongodb-c-sharp-filter-and-get-all-subdocuments)

There reason I am using projection is to omit some fields which the user should not see (depending on the role). Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to change the signature of the method to *not* be async?

Comment: I can, but would like to preferably keep it async. Will try without the async and see how it goes.

Comment: no go. I the following error: The result operation MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Expressions.ResultOperators.ListResultOperator is not supported.

Comment: maybe this ? https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver.html

Answer (score 4):

The problem occurs in that line:

`Sales = l.Sales.Where(a => a.Owner.Id == userId || a.Manager.Id == userId).ToList()`

What happens here ? MongoDB driver takes this **expression** and tries to translate it to aggregation framework syntax. There's a [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator which can be run on nested collection and driver is able to translate `.Where()` to that operator however there's nothing corresponding for `.ToList()` at the end of that expression and that's why it fails.

So the fix is fairly easy: you just need to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>` for `Sales` property and then get rid of that `.ToList()` so your code will look like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Listing>> LoadAllUserListings(string userId)
{
    var result = _context.Listing.Aggregate().Match(l => l.OwnerId == userId || l.Sales.Any(a => a.Owner.Id == userId)).
            Project(l => new Listing
            {
                Id = l.Id,
                Reference = l.Reference,
                OwnerId = l.OwnerId,
                Sales = l.Sales.Where(a => a.Owner.Id == userId || a.Manager.Id == userId),
                Products = l.Products,
                Status = l.Status,
                DueDate = l.DueDate
            }).ToListAsync();

    return await result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It still exceptions when it is returned to the calling method. For the sake of getting this done, I have restructured the class and no longer need to perform this query. When I have more time I will try to get this to work.